# T-SQL How to create function that compares string, checks difference, and do special function

Tags: sql, t-sql

First - sorry for my english. Second - i'm learning t-SQL.

---

**Goal:**

I want to get difference between two strings, then check in which column is this difference. If the difference is in first column, do something, if in second column - do something else.

---

**What I'm actually doing**

Column 'messages' is a string which contains list of ID. So i am replacing all '#' with ',' and deleting last ',' what gives to me **ActualID** and **BeforeID** column. See below:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @string3 VARCHAR(512);

SET @string = '41#42#43#44#45#46#47#48#49#50#51#52#53#54#55#56#57#58#59#';
SET @string2 = REPLACE((SELECT messages FROM USERS WHERE userid = 4), '#', ', ' )
SET @string3 = left(@string2, len(@string2) - 1);
SET @string2 = REPLACE(@string, '#', ', ' )
SET @string = left(@string2, len(@string2) - 1);
SELECT @string3 as ActualID, @string as BeforeID
```

[image: myquery]

---

So now, I want compare **BeforeID** with **ActualID**. For example:

In BeforeID we have `1, 2, 3` / In **ActualID** `1, 2, 3, 4`

In example above `4` was added. So, if it was added I want to add it to `@AddedElements`.

If `4, 5, 7` were added then `SELECT @AddedElements as AddedElements` should return `4, 5, 7` (With comas)

But, that's not all.

If **BeforeID** = `1, 5, 10, 14` and **ActualID** = `1, 5, 14` I want, that element which is in **BeforeID**, but not in **AcutalID** will be added to @DeletedElements.

So `SELECT @DeletedElements as DeletedElements` should return `10`

Added elements/Deleted elements should be returned once. I mean, full result what I want to Earn should be

`SELECT @AddedElements as AddedElements, @DeletedElements as DeletedElements`

---

Is it possible? If, then how to do it?

Comment: Does SQL Server support array datatypes? If not, you'll need to rethink how you're going about this.

Comment: i thinkt it can be done without any arrays

Comment: If you want to make things harder than they need to be, then sure. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to start by saying that this is just poor design; but having said that, I've also found myself in all kinds of situations where I couldn't change the way things worked, only try to make them work better in the current configuration.  Therefore, I recommend something like this:

1: Create a UDF (User-Defined Function) that can handle splitting the strings and returning them in table-formed data that you can work with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_StringDelimiter]
/*********************************************************
**  Takes Parameter "LIST" and transforms it for use    **
**  to select individual values or ranges of values.    **
**                                                      **
**  EX: 'This,is,a,test' = 'This' 'Is' 'A' 'Test'       **
*********************************************************/
    (
          @LIST             VARCHAR(8000)
         ,@DELIMITER        VARCHAR(255)
    )

RETURNS @TABLE TABLE 
    ( 
         [RowID] INT IDENTITY
        ,[Value] VARCHAR(255)
    )
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
         @LISTLENGTH AS SMALLINT
        ,@LISTCURSOR AS SMALLINT
        ,@VALUE AS VARCHAR(255)
    ;
    SELECT 
         @LISTLENGTH = LEN(@LIST) - LEN(REPLACE(@LIST,@DELIMITER,'')) + 1
        ,@LISTCURSOR = 1
        ,@VALUE = ''
    ;
    WHILE @LISTCURSOR <= @LISTLENGTH
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @TABLE (Value)
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN @LISTCURSOR < @LISTLENGTH
                    THEN SUBSTRING(@LIST,1,PATINDEX('%' + @DELIMITER + '%',@LIST) - 1)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@LIST,1,LEN(@LIST))
            END
        ;
        SET @LIST = STUFF(@LIST,1,PATINDEX('%' + @DELIMITER + '%',@LIST),'')
        ;       
        SET @LISTCURSOR = @LISTCURSOR + 1
        ;
    END
    ;
    RETURN
    ;
END
;
```

2: Consider dropping the whole "Switching out commas" thing, because it's pointless - the function I've written here takes two arguments: The string itself, and the delimiter (the mini-string that separates the individual strings within the big string, in your case '#') Then you just have to do a couple of quick comparisons to find out what was added and what was deleted.

```
DECLARE 
     @AddedElements VARCHAR(255) = ''
    ,@DeletedElements VARCHAR(255) = ''
    ,@ActualID VARCHAR(255) = '41#42#43#44#45#46#47#48#49#50#51#52#53#54#55#56#57#58#59#'
    ,@BeforeID VARCHAR(255) = '41#42#43#44#45#46#47#48#50#51#52#53#54#55#56#57#58#59#60#'
;

SET @AddedElements = @AddedElements + 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT ', ' + Value
        FROM dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(@ActualID,'#')
        WHERE Value NOT IN
            (
            SELECT Value
            FROM dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(@BeforeID,'#')
            )
        GROUP BY ', ' + Value
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,3,255)
;

SET @DeletedElements = @DeletedElements + 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT ', ' + Value
        FROM dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(@BeforeID,'#')
        WHERE Value NOT IN
            (
            SELECT Value
            FROM dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(@ActualID,'#')
            )
        GROUP BY ', ' + Value
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,3,255)
;

SELECT @AddedElements AS AddedElements,@DeletedElements AS DeletedElements
;
```

Using this method, if you add a value to `@ActualID` that does not exist in `@BeforeID`, it will show up in `@AddedElements`.

Likewise , if you remove an element from `@ActualID` that had previously existed in `@BeforeID`, it will show up in `@DeletedElements`.

All of this is, of course, assuming that the dynamic string (the one really being compared here) is the `@ActualID`.  I operated with the understanding that `@BeforeID` is actually a stored value in the DB, and `@ActualID` is a dynamic string being passed in from...somewhere.  If this is wrong, update me and I'll change the tactic appropriately.

**Quick note:** It's important to me to point out that this is just one way of dealing with a situation like this, and I'm sure there are better ways; but with the information I have, it's the best I could come up with without spending too much time and energy on it.